# Selenium web driver cannot click a button while element is visible and clickable, throws org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: java, html, scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following menu bar which I try to test with selenium web driver:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="btn-group pull-left">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="id-home_prevButton" style="min-height:10px;min-width:10px" hidden="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="id-home_nextButton" style="min-height:10px;min-width:10px" hidden="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  </div>
  <span class="span-title" id="id-home_title">Home</span>
  <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="id-home_infoButton" hidden="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" id="id-home_dropDownButton" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" hidden="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i><span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right simple-title-dropdown" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#home" id="id-home_menu_homeLink">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button ids are unique.

Selenium scala code clicking the button is:

```
def wEPrint(description: String, wE: WebElement): String = {
  s"$description = wE.getTagName: ${wE.getTagName}  wE.getText: ${wE.getText}  wE.getSize: ${wE.getSize}  wE.isDisplayed: ${wE.isDisplayed}  wE.isEnabled: ${wE.isEnabled}  wE.isSelected: ${wE.isSelected}"
}

...


log.debug("Find id-home_prevButton")

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
val waitPrevButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
val prevButton = driver.findElement(By.id("id-home_prevButton"))
log.debug(wEPrint("prevButton",prevButton))
waitPrevButton.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id-home_prevButton")))
log.debug("id-home_prevButton.click")
prevButton.click()
```

sbt console output is:

```
22:49:11.378 [run-main-3] DEBUG com.example.selex.MWLExp$ - Find id-home_prevButton
22:49:11.539 [run-main-3] DEBUG com.example.selex.MWLExp$ - prevButton = wE.getTagName: button  wE.getText:   wE.getSize: (40, 34)  wE.isDisplayed: true  wE.isEnabled: true  wE.isSelected: false
22:49:11.588 [run-main-3] DEBUG com.example.selex.MWLExp$ - id-home_prevButton.click
[error] (run-main-3) org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
[error] Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
[error] System info: host: 'tra', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-72-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
[error] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
[error] Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.T6j4aNCkep6a, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=4.4.0-72-generic, moz:processID=51151.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux}]
[error] Session ID: 1349d85f-d360-4725-963c-f6ec277e308c
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'tra', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-72-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.T6j4aNCkep6a, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=4.4.0-72-generic, moz:processID=51151.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux}]
Session ID: 1349d85f-d360-4725-963c-f6ec277e308c
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
    at com.example.selex.MWLExp$.run01(MWLExp.scala:92)
    at simple.MainJVM$.main(DemoJVM.scala:44)
    at simple.MainJVM.main(DemoJVM.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Selenium test code can find the button, it is displayed and enabled, visibilityOfElementLocated succeeds but clicking throws ElementNotInteractableException.

When I run the app without selenium, button is visible and I can click it and it works without any errors.

In selenium IDE clicking the button works OK. Selenium IDE Java code for clicking the button is:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id-home_prevButton")).click();
```

EDIT

I modified the code slightly:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
val waitPrevButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
val prevButton = driver.findElement(By.id("id-home_prevButton"))
log.debug(wEPrint("prevButton",prevButton))
waitPrevButton.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id-home_prevButton")))
log.debug("id-home_prevButton.click")
//prevButton.click()
//prevButton.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
prevButton.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

And now the exception message is:

```
23:30:56.497 [run-main-6] DEBUG com.example.selex.MWLExp$ - Find id-home_prevButton
23:30:56.735 [run-main-6] DEBUG com.example.selex.MWLExp$ - prevButton = wE.getTagName: button  wE.getText:   wE.getSize: (40, 34)  wE.isDisplayed: true  wE.isEnabled: true  wE.isSelected: false
23:30:56.798 [run-main-6] DEBUG com.example.selex.MWLExp$ - id-home_prevButton.click
[error] (run-main-6) org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible
[error] Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
[error] System info: host: 'tra', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-72-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
[error] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
[error] Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.gBopOPHPUrCL, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=4.4.0-72-generic, moz:processID=54936.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux}]
[error] Session ID: eba7323c-6412-4ed7-a91f-3f897b3ec83f
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'tra', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-72-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.gBopOPHPUrCL, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=4.4.0-72-generic, moz:processID=54936.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux}]
Session ID: eba7323c-6412-4ed7-a91f-3f897b3ec83f
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:96)
    at com.example.selex.MWLExp$.run01(MWLExp.scala:93)
    at simple.MainJVM$.main(DemoJVM.scala:44)
    at simple.MainJVM.main(DemoJVM.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

So now it says that element is not visible although visibilityOfElementLocated has succeeded and it is displayed and enabled.

What's the reason for this exception and how to fix it?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 8):

Use javascriptExecutor to click the element by embedding javascript. By using javascript executor we can run the javascript on the driver.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id-home_prevButton");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: This solution worked for me after getting the exception. ""org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <input id="..... type="checkbox"> could not be scrolled into view"

Comment: My final code: `String cssElm = target.getCssOrXPathSelector();

        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(cssElm)));
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssElm));
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
       ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem which was fixed by:

```
String id = element.getAttribute("id");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('#id').click();");
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Selenium Advanced User Interaction API](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Advanced-User-Interactions) mentioned e.g. [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2556): 
I could fix this issue. Modified selenium code is as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
val waitPrevButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
val prevButton = driver.findElement(By.id("id-home_prevButton"))
log.debug(wEPrint("prevButton",prevButton))
waitPrevButton.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id-home_prevButton")))
log.debug("id-home_prevButton.click")
//prevButton.click()
//prevButton.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
//prevButton.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(prevButton).click().perform()
```

This fixes the issue but I would still like to know the reason for the `ElementNotInteractableException` and why selenium complained "Element is not visible" after successfull v`isibilityOfElementLocated` test. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there some shifts about this question?

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be resolve by simply using Implicit wait because web page loaded page completely then its find elements.

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS); driver.get("URL");`

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. I captured the same element by using different Xpath and it worked. I also don't know why. Below is my case:

`//a[contains(text(),'%s')]` -> did not work.

`//a//span[contains(text(),'%s')]` -> worked.

This is my HTML code:

```
<a data-gtm-event="mbn-event-link" data-gtm-category="mbn-listing" data-gtm-action="home-category-l0-c3" href="/mua-ban-nha-dat-cho-thue-toan-quoc-l0-c3" title="Bất động sản ">
    <span class="clearfix">
        <span class="category-icon"><span class="icon icon-cat-3"></span></span>
        <span class="category-name">Bất động sản</span>
    </span>
</a>
<span class="clearfix">
    <span class="category-icon"><span class="icon icon-cat-3"></span></span>
    <span class="category-name">Bất động sản</span>
</span>
```